# How to change the text of a button in a callback ? (Android)

Tags: android, bluetooth, callback, scope

Here's my app :
It does a bluetooth scan, and the scanning function has callback when it finds a device.
I would like to change the text of a particular button from "Searching" to "Connect" once it finds a particular device (which it recognizes with its device name).

However the button is not reachable in the scope of the callback.

Is there any way to do this ? I think this is purely a scope problem, and I have little experience with this kind of things.

Code :

```
 Context context;
    context = this;

    update_str = "";

    Button ConnectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Connect);
    ConnectButton.setText("Waiting for device to be found");

    Button ScanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Scan);

    ScanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                      public void onClick(View v) {
                                          btAdapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);
                                      }
                                  });

    BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {

            update_str = update_str.concat(" " + device.getName());
            ((TextView)findViewById (R.id.text)).setText (update_str);
            nom_device = device.getName();
            if (nom_device=="bill_gates"){

                context.ConnectButton.setText(nom_device);

                context.ConnectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), false, context.btleGattCallback);
                    }

            });
        }

        }
    };
```

Compiler error log :

```js
C:\Code\Grizz\app\src\main\java\com\grizz\grizzmvp\MainActivity.java
Error:(84, 28) error: cannot find symbol variable ConnectButton
Error:(89, 117) error: cannot find symbol variable btleGattCallback
Error:(86, 28) error: cannot find symbol variable ConnectButton
Note: C:\Code\Grizz\app\src\main\java\com\grizz\grizzmvp\MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1.381 secs
Information:4 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: You don't have to find the button by Id everytime you want to change something. After you declared it in the first line, the second line could simply be: `ConnectButton.setText(Searching...");`. Oh and what a cool name you have!

Comment: Why do you have a Button you called "ConnectButton", which has the id "Connect" and another Button with id "ConnectButton"? It would also be helpful to see your logcat/ error log

Comment: That was unintended and has been corrected as you suggested.

Comment: Have you tried declaring the Button(s) as final?

Comment: If i declare them as final, is it still possible to change callbacks & text ? I thought the goal of final was to prevent any further change.

Comment: I have solved the problem for the buttons with a disgusting workaround - referring to the button via ((Button).findViewById(R.id.Connect) instead of ConnectButton or context.ConnectButton - but the problem remains for btleGattCallback. it's defined outside of the callback and I can't access it via any ID or whatever

Comment: I think it will still be possible. You can't assing another Button to that variable, but you can assign new attributes to the same Button. Another thing: try not to compare Strings with the `==` operator. Use `nom_device.equals("bill_gates")` instead, it return true if both are equal.

Comment: Thanks, adding final actually made it work. Plus btleGattCallback was defined after its call in the callback. Hope to see you on other boards, Barthy ;)

Comment: Good! I would be glad if you could accept my answer I just posted below :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When an anonymous inner class is defined within the body of a method,
>   all variables declared final in the scope of that method are
>   accessible from within the inner class. For scalar values, once it has
>   been assigned, the value of the final variable cannot change. For
>   object values, the reference cannot change. This allows the Java
>   compiler to "capture" the value of the variable at run-time and store
>   a copy as a field in the inner class. Once the outer method has
>   terminated and its stack frame has been removed, the original variable
>   is gone but the inner class's private copy persists in the class's own
>   memory.

```
final Button ConnectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Connect);
ConnectButton.setText("Waiting for device to be found");

final Button ScanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Scan);
ScanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btAdapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);
    }
});

BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {
        update_str = update_str.concat(" " + device.getName());
        ((TextView)findViewById (R.id.text)).setText (update_str);
        nom_device = device.getName();
        if (nom_device.equals("bill_gates")){

            ConnectButton.setText(nom_device);
            ConnectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), false, context.btleGattCallback);
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  Context context ; //Global
  context=this;  //In oncreate of activity,

 // construction of button 
 Button ConnectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Connect);
 ((Button)findViewById(R.id.ConnectButton)).setText("Searching.."); 

 public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {

            nom_device = device.getName();
            if (nom_device=="bill_gates"){ 
                ((Button)findViewById(R.id.ConnectButton)).setText("Connect");

              // This part fails because the callback doesn't recognize ConnectButton. It's out of his scope. 
                context.ConnectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), false, btleGattCallback);
                    } 

            });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem remains, even  though the var context seems to be recognized, as opposed to ConnectButton...?

Comment: I am not sure about the issue, can you update code as you see , maybe some screenshots with exact error that AS or compiler gives you